# When rendering with qmd, rmd is automatically generated

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm not good at English, so sorry for my bad English.

The issue is when rendering with qmd, rmd is automatically generated
I made .rmd file and tried to render it, but automatically make rmd file and rendering always stop at a chunk which read csv file(about 4.5GB).

[image]
[image]

I was able to successfully read chunks in the qmd file.
Why is the rmd file created?

If I delete the rmd file and render it again, the rmd file is created again.
No matter how much running, It can't read csv forever.

Please help me